# How can I install/use "odt-meta" for Ubuntu to check metadata for odt-files?

Tags: 20.10

I have a file written in LibreOffice. I want to check the meta data for it.
How can I install/use "odt-meta" for Ubuntu to check metadata for odt-files?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see `odt-meta` on my system -- is this `odt-meta` provided by `calibre` package ([see man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/odt-meta.1.html))?  I'm also using `calibre` on Ubuntu (20.04), but the version provided by the ubuntu repo didn't work / was too old, so I ended up installing the latest `calibre` from `tar.gz` (version 5.x), and it didn't include `odt-meta`, but rather [ebook-meta](https://manual.calibre-ebook.com/generated/en/ebook-meta.html), so I can't actually test this out at the moment. The new `ebook-meta` utility also has a command-line "help" usage option (`-h`), so perhaps the old `odt-meta` might also; you could try running `odt-meta -h`, and then just probably do: `$ odt-meta {filename.odt}`

Fwiw, for this reason (`odt-meta` no longer is provided w/ later versions of calibre), I wouldn't presume to expect `odt-meta` to be there in the future, so you might consider a different utility to check ODT metadata, eg [exiftool](https://exiftool.org/exiftool_pod.html#READING-EXAMPLES), [apache tika](https://tika.apache.org/1.24.1/gettingstarted.html#Using_Tika_as_a_command_line_utility), etc.